# cassandra connection in flask controller functions

Tags: python, flask

I have the following code in a function called in flask using datastax cassandra driver

```
cassandra = Cluster(current_ap.config['DATABASE_NODES'])
session = cassandra.connect('keyspace')
session.execute_query(...)
session.shutdown()
cassandra.shutdown()
```

So everytime someone hits a specific url, it creates new cluster new connection and closes. I believe this is expensive. How can I create a global session object to use for all requests coming to my flask application? What is the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a cluster when initializing your app once and attach it to your flask application or creating it in a global accessible place and whenever you need it, just import it and use it.

Comment: Should I use the cluster or the session; the document of cassandra-driver from datastax doesn't say much about pooling connections... Like c3po for jpa and MySQL for example.

Comment: How do I set it as a global object?